# Windows 10 is taking too long to start up

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, laptop

I clean installed Windows 10 Pro on August 23 and then updated.

Windows 10 is taking almost 4-6 minutes - after pressing the power key to a usable desktop to appear.

I am using Samsung laptop, Intel i5 3rd Gen, 500 Gb HDD.

In my attempt to solve this long-time boot issue, I did the followings;

1. I have done tried many suggestions that are available on internet blogs, including - disabling the start-up programs including my AMD graphics from start-up programs (except my ESET Anti-virus), stopping all background apps (hoping they won't use the system memory, and the battery will last long).
2. I even contacted Windows official support, and an agent accessed my laptop virtually and tried to do something (I remember she increased the virtual memory, which at that time reduced the start-up time to little above 2 minutes for once two starts) but the problem persists.
3. I even removed the lock screen and now go directly to password screen when laptop starts, to avoid the few seconds delay.

Additional issues;

1. It takes almost 10-15 seconds for the taskbar icons to appear and become usable after the desktop appears.
2. The battery is draining fast.
3. Many of my Hotkeys are not working.

I did an `sfc /scannow` run on my CMD; it says no integrity violations.

Please help.

Comment: Check the SMART data of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Run Windows 10 Admin Tools, Resource Monitor and let it run for 15 minutes.  There is a Disk, CPU, Memory and Network section. Look in the Disk and CPU sections to see what processes are using either or both.

4 minutes to fully started with a hard drive is about normal. But running but battery draining fast and Hot Keys not working is not normal.

Do a full scan with Windows Defender or with ESET to look for viruses. Follow this with a scan using Malwarebytes

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same problem for over a year. An SSD & enough RAM will work if no additional Hardware issues are there.

> I'd suggest you to add an SSD (Solid State Drive) of about 250 GB (Samsung is better).
>   Make it 1st boot device. Use it fully for Windows, means do not create partitions on it.
>   Keep the old HDD for data storage only...
>   Also check the RAM (Remove it, Clean it and reinsert) I'd recomend 4GB of it.

I'm sure if you have enough RAM with the SSD & a fresh Windows Setup, the PC boots in less than 30 seconds.
Also I'd like to add that if you have a Genuine Windows license, Windows defender will take care of all the Viruses, Malwares, etc.

Enjoy